# SQLDroid Vs Android internal JDBC driver

Tags: android, sqlite

I am developing an android application which uses the `SQLite` database. In that case, I am in confusion which driver to use?

`SQLDroid` driver from this page https://github.com/SQLDroid/SQLDroid or the internal android `JDBC` driver. Please share your suggestions regarding which one is best to use?

Comment: Why would you use either driver, rather than the standard Android database classes?

Comment: The answer is actually "neither" unless you have a mountain of legacy code that requires JDBC. The correct way is to use `SQLiteDatabase` - created by a subclass of `SQLiteOpenHelper`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android does not come with a normal JDBC driver. If you need JDBC you can use sqldroid otherwise you have to use the android internal database [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/package-summary.html).
If you realy need JDBC, keep in mind, that the SQLDroid implementation does not provide all JDBC driver features. There are many methods that are not implemented!

Edit: On Android 2.3, I guess, there is an undocumented JDBC driver named `SQLite.JDBCDriver` located in  `/system/framework/sqlite-jdbc.jar`, but I recommend not to use this!! This will probably crash on most other android versions.

Answer (score 0):

We ported the driver in context of another project. You can retain and include the .jar file from https://github.com/plingpling/Asper/blob/master/source/libs/sqlite.jar

Driver is based on the Berkeley implementation and should include most of the driver features.
I has not been tested extensively - so be aware.

Comment: Try to add information or code from the link to your answer, this makes the readers more easy and all users are not able to access external links.